# Want to open a new tab

Tags: php, html

I've some issues, I've got an POST form with 2 submits.

1. submit needs to go to the payment file. (works)
2. submit needs to open a new tab where it also executes the PHP script.

I had the 2 submit working with target="a_blank", but whenever I tried it, it didn't executed my PHP script.

I also have tried to combine javascript with my PHP script but it did not work. So i'm desperately look for an answer.

So my question is how can I create something in my PHP script where it creates a new tab.

My form:

```
<div id="form-actie-container">
<span style="margin:auto; display:table; color: red; "><?php echo $error; ?></span>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">


    <label  for="name">Welkom bericht</label> <br>
    <textarea type="text" id="Welkom-Bericht" name="Welkom-Bericht" placeholder="Teksts voor welkom"></textarea> 

    <br>        
    <label  for="name">Arrangement bericht</label> <br>
    <textarea type="text" id="Arrangement-Bericht" name="Arrangement-Bericht" placeholder="Tekts voor je Arrangement"></textarea>
    <br>
     <label  for="name">Maasduin actie bericht</label> <br>
    <textarea type="text" id="Maasduin-Actie-Bericht" name="Maasduin-Actie-Bericht" placeholder="Tekts voor Maasduin actie"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
        <label>Foto-1</label>
    <br>
        <input type="file" name="image1" id="image" accept="image/*" "/>
    <br>
    <br>
        <label>Foto-2</label>
    <br>
        <input type="file" name="image2" id="image" accept="image/*" "/>
    <br>
    <br>
        <label>Foto-3 </label>
    <br>
        <input type="file" name="image3" id="image" accept="image/*" "/>
    <br>
    <br>
        <label>Foto-4</label>
    <br>
        <input type="file" name="image4" id="image" accept="image/*" "/>
    <br>
    <br>
        <label>Foto-5</label>
    <br>
        <input type="file" name="image5" id="image" accept="image/*" "/>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="Actie-Code">Je email</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="email"b name="email" placeholder="Je email..">
    <br>

    <label for="Actie-Code">Je actie code</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="code"  name="code" placeholder="Je Code..">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="actieSubmit" value="Betalen..">
    <input type="submit" name="LookSubmit"  value="Hoe ziet het eruit?..">
  </form>
</div>
```

My PHP Script:

```
    if (isset($_POST['LookSubmit'])) {

    $welkom = $_SESSION['welkom'] = $_POST["Welkom-Bericht"];
    $arrangement = $_SESSION['arrangement'] = $_POST["Arrangement-Bericht"];
    $pas = $_SESSION['pas'] = $_POST["Maasduin-Actie-Bericht"];
    $code = $_SESSION['code'] = $_POST['code'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];

    $confrimActie = '1';

    $found = FALSE;

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `ms-activiteiten` WHERE ActieCode = ? AND MaasduinEmail = ? AND Confirmed = ? ");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $code , $email, $Confirmed);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();

    foreach ($hotels as $key => $hotel){
        if ($code == $hotel['ActieCode'] && $email == $hotel['MaasduinEmail'] && $hotel['Confirmed'] == '1') {
        $ActieVerify = $_SESSION['verifyActieCode'] = $confirmCodeVerifyActie = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), -10);

        $naam = $hotel['MaasduinNaam'];

        mkdir('image/' . $naam);
        $destination1   = "image/" . $naam . "/" . $_FILES['image1']['name'];
        $filename       = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination1);

        mkdir('image/' . $naam);
        $destination2   = "image/" . $naam . "/" . $_FILES['image2']['name'];
        $filename       = $_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination2);

        mkdir('image/' . $naam);
        $destination3   = "image/" . $naam . "/" . $_FILES['image3']['name'];
        $filename       = $_FILES['image3']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination3);

        mkdir('image/' . $naam);
        $destination4   = "image/" . $naam . "/" . $_FILES['image4']['name'];
        $filename       = $_FILES['image4']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination4);

        mkdir('image/' . $naam);
        $destination5   = "image/" . $naam . "/" . $_FILES['image5']['name'];
        $filename       = $_FILES['image5']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination5);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `ms-activiteiten` SET MaasduinWelkom = ?, MaasduinArrangement = ?, MaasduinPasInfo = ?, Confirmcode = ?,  MaasduinImgDialog1 = ?, MaasduinImgDialog2 = ?, MaasduinImgDialog3 = ?, MaasduinImgDialog4= ?, MaasduinImgDialog5 =? WHERE ActieCode = '$code'");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $welkom, $arrangement, $pas, $ActieVerify, $destination1, $destination2, $destination3, $destination4, $destination5);
        $stmt->execute();


        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `ms-overnachten` SET MaasduinWelkom = ?, MaasduinArrangement = ?, MaasduinPasInfo = ?, Confirmcode = ?, MaasduinImgDialog1 = ? WHERE ActieCode = '$code'");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $welkom, $arrangement, $pas, $ActieVerify, $destination);
        $stmt->execute();


        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `ms-etenendrinken` SET MaasduinWelkom = ?, MaasduinArrangement = ?, MaasduinPasInfo = ?, Confirmcode = ?, MaasduinImgDialog1 = ? WHERE ActieCode = '$code'");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $welkom, $arrangement, $pas, $ActieVerify, $destination);
        $stmt->execute();

        header("LOCATION: test.php");

        }elseif (!$found && $code !== $hotel['ActieCode'] && $email !== $hotel['MaasduinEmail'] && $hotel['Confirmed'] == '1') {
            $error =  "<b>".'ERROR:  ' . "</b>" . 'Code and email do not match!';
            $found = TRUE;
        }elseif(!$found && $code == $hotel['ActieCode'] && $email == $hotel['MaasduinEmail'] && $hotel['Confirmed'] == '0'){
            $error =  "<b>".'ERROR:  ' . "</b>" . 'Accommodatie is nog niet geaccepteerd.';
            $found = TRUE;
        } 

    }
```

Comment: What did your javascript attempt look like? That is certainly the method I would choose to achieve your goal

Comment: something like this:
<script type="text/javascript">  
   window.open('localhost/maasduinenpas/test.php', '_blank');
</script>

Comment: I recommend you have a look at the examples for javascript image uploads here to get you started. I think your php needs some work too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I've got it working now. needed to allow pop-ups.